# How to check for a specific exception in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, error-handling

I am writing a Node.js application, and inside one of its code blocks various exceptions may be thrown (by 3rd party code I call). Now I want to react on these exceptions, hence I do:

```
try {
  // Call 3rd party code
} catch (e) {
  // Handle e
}
```

Basically, this works fine, but ... how do I differ between different exceptions?

They all unfortunately have `Error` as constructor, hence this is no viable way. I may use the `message` property, but of course this is not the nicest way (as I am dependent on the fact the the message will never change, which is - IMHO - more probable than that the constructor changes).

Any ideas?

PS: Concretely - I need to react on SSL error while trying to do a `tls.connect`. How do I detect that it's an SSL error?

Comment: Well if there is just a specific message differentiating it from other errors you can't

Comment: The only way to check is to interrogate the `message` using string comparisons and/or regex.

Comment: doesn't tls.connect emit 'error' event instead of throwing an exeption?

Comment: Okay, then I have to rely on the message to stay the same in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most errors that are system-level errors wrapped into javascript error objects will have a `code` property and `errno` you can compare against. The list is defined [in uv.h in the node.js source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/include/uv.h#L73). That's probably your 2nd choice, with preference being

1. instanceof where possible
2. `code` or `errno`
3. `message`

But the fact is sometimes you just have to look at `message`. Given the dynamic and loose typing of javascript and the fact that exceptions in general don't play a big role in node.js, there will be cases where checking the message is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a try/catch structure in Node, as I don't think it will work due to the asynchronous nature of Node (unless you're using basic, synchronous code).

Assuming you're utilizing asynchronous functions/packages, you'll probably have more luck checking the err status in a callback function.